# Could Hera Agathon really be Mitochondrial Eve?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the [final episode](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Daybreak,_Part_II) of the re-imagined Battlestar Galactica series, the human-Cylon hybrid child Hera is revealed to be [Mitochondrial Eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve) (the woman from whom all living humans today descend, on their mother's side).

Does this mean that she had one or more aboriginal partners (since the arrivals determined that their genetic compatibility with the local population was necessary for long term survival)? And that all human lineages--both aboriginal and colonial--that did not produce a female child who is a descendant of hers went extinct?

Comment: It doesn't mean that other lineages didn't produce, it just means that all the other lineages intermingled with Hera's.

Comment: Ugh, that whole ending of the series is best left forgotten.

Comment: I love how no one ever brings up the big possibility of a massive die-off caused be the BSG survivors suddenly intermingling with the aboriginals... the survivors of many of the ships lived in cramped conditions and I thought there were big issues with disease running rampant.

Comment: Am I the only one who misread this as *midichlorian* Eve? Darn, there's a word I'd like to forget.

Comment: @Wikis So Hera was the prophesied *One*, who was supposed to bring balance to the Force and free Zion?

Comment: @bblake what was wrong with it?

Comment: You mean aside from the fact that it was an idiotic ending, answered almost none of the major questions that were outstanding and those that did get answered made very little sense.  Add to it that it created dozens, if not hundreds of new questions that will never be answered.  The entire thing seemed to be a massive thrown together at the last second "Help, how do we end this show, I have no good ideas? finale?  As finales go, it rates right at the bottom with Lost and Seinfeld.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does this mean that she had one or more aboriginal partners?

Either Hera did or a sufficient number of her female descendants did. For instance, if she had two human-cylon-hybrid daughters and both of them had aboriginal partners, she would still qualify as Mitocondrial Eve.

It doesn't mean that every other line went extinct. Since mitocondria are passed down from the mother, it's possible that most of our ancestors were natives. For instance, if my mother was Hera but my father was aboriginal, I'd have her mitocondria. If Hera was my mother's mother, but all of my other ancestors (including my mother's father) were native, I'd still have them. A hundred generations later, it's possible that my family tree has 2^100 members of aboriginal heritage, yet because my grand(x 100)-mother was Hera, she's responsible for generating my ATP.

So we could all be 99.999% of aboriginal heritage, except for [mtDNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA).